# Some of the books was/were either of them was/were

Tags: word-usage

According to OAD *[ "none of the" + plural noun ]* takes either a plural or a singular verb.

But do "some of the", "either of the/you," "both" and "both of the/my" take a singular or a plural verb too?

1. None of the messages was/were important.
2. A few of the messages were/was important.
3. Some of the messages were/was important.
4. Some of the cream was added to the cake. Only a singular verb.
5. A little of the cream was added to the cake. Only a singular verb.
6. None of the news was important. Only a singular verb.
7. Does/do either of them speak English?
8. Both my friends speak English.
9. Both of my friends speak/speaks English.
   [image]

Comment: Both is always more than one, so *Both of my friends speak**s** English* sounds odd.

Comment: _Some of [countable]_ is plural (even if in the particular case it turned out to be only one). _Some of [uncountable]_ is singular.

Comment: Have you tried to find the answer on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** The simplest and central rule here is: The verb should match the subject. Sometimes, when a situation is confusing, it helps to strip away "extra" words. Try eliminating the "of the" phrase:

> Some were important.
> A few were important.
> Both were important.

All these are plurals; "Some was" would be wrong.

**2.** *Either of* is different. It's singular. Because you're making an "either/or" choice: *Either of these muffins would be delicious* means "Either this one would, or that one would." (Note, this is about *either of*. There can be constructions using *either* that would be plural; e.g. you could compare two plural groups: *"Either your friends or mine are wrong"*.)

**3.** Similarly, the rationale behind *none* being singular is that it's a kind of contraction of *not one*. "Not one **was** important"—that is, "**One was** not important."

**4.** We're talking here about strict, official grammatical correctness. "Either of" and "None of" are often used with plural verb forms simply because the plural group comes so close to the verb, so it "sounds right." If you're in a formal, academic context, use the singular with these, but if someone in casual conversation says "None of the messages **were** important," it's excessively finicky to find fault with them.

Comment: do I understand correctly "some of" is used with a singular verb and  with an uncountable noun as in some of the news is, but with a countable noun some is followed by a plural verb "some of the books were interesting" not "some of the books was interesting". Unlike "none of the books" are/is.  Right?

Comment: @AntoniaA True, non-count nouns change things. Again, try omitting "of": "Some news is boring. Some books are interesting." But you can't even use "none," "either," or "both" with non-count: "None news is...?"

Comment: @AntoniaA Well, as I think about it—again, in casual conversation you might hear "None **of the** news is interesting." That construction might be a bad idea in a formal academic context, but again, is common enough in other contexts, even if the words don't make perfect logical sense. (Not one of the non-count thing?)

Comment: ,There is a list of quantifiers that are used with countable and uncountable nouns in my book. "None of"  is shown with both countable and uncountable nouns. I will post the screenshot for you to see. The book doesn't say that "none of" isn't used with uncountable nouns. The others I was asking about aren't mentioned.  I am glad I was right about "some of" with "is"  being wrong in "some of the books is" but in  "A few of the messages were/was important" and "Does/do either of them speak English" are both singular and plural verbs correct? In examples 2 and 7.

Comment: @AntoniaA Again, we might be dealing with multiple levels of "correct." "Do either of them" is so common as to be acceptable in all but the strictest contexts... but in that strictest context, no, it's wrong. We've just inverted the word order, but it's "Either of them [does] speak" and "Does either of them speak." Note, the "common but technically wrong" usages are all about the quantifiers that select a singular out of a multiple group. *Nobody* uses the ones that ought to be plural as singulars; no one says "A few was," because "a few" is by definition more than one thing.